# How to get user info into in visualforce / salesforce

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

I'm trying to get user email into salesforce visualforce. here is the form, I'm very new to salesforce, please forget me for any missing information.

I'd like to know if salesforce has a public class for user email, firstname and etc

```
<apex:page standardController="AcctSeed__Cash_Disbursement_Batch__c">
   <form id="MyForm" method="POST">
              <input type="hidden" id="checkbook_var"

                UserFirtname="{!XXname}"
                UserLastname="{!XXname}"
                user-email ='{!XXEmail}'
/>
              <script src="some.js" class="checkbook-button" id="api_js">
              </script>
    </form>        
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the built-in "User" object.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_user.htm

```
 UserFirtname={!$User.FirstName}
 UserLastname={!$User.LastName}
 user-email ={!$User.Email}
```